# Живой пример постинга в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP. XML-RPC.
Кто покажет живой пример постинга в Wordpress с категорей и парой тэгов, в результате должен быть показан идентификатор новой записи, вообщем классика ?

Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Я пользуюсь таким кодом:

```
require_once ('IXR_Library.php');

$client = new IXR_Client('http://my_blog.com/xmlrpc.php');
$client->timeout = 60000;

$requestData[0] = 0; //id блога
$requestData[1] = 'admin'; //имя пользователя
$requestData[2] = 'pass'; //пароль

$post = array();

$post['post_title'] = 'New Post';
$post['post_excerpt'] = 'Short description';
$post['post_content'] = 'This story about ...';
$post['post_status'] = 'draft';
$post['post_type'] = 'my_custom_post_type'; //тип поста
$post['post_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$post['post_modified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//формируем массив с терминами таксономий
$terms = array();
$terms['taxonomy_1'][] = (int)$term['term_id_1'];
$terms['taxonomy_1'][] = (int)$term['term_id_2'];
$terms['taxonomy_2'][] = (int)$term['term_id_3'];
$terms['taxonomy_3'][] = (int)$term['term_id_4'];

$post['tax_input'] = $terms;

$requestData[3] = $post;

if (!$client->query('my.publish_post', $requestData)) {
    echo 'Publish Post error: '.$client->getErrorMessage();
    return;
}

$publishedPost = $client->getResponse();
```

[Источник](http://www.simplecoding.org/wordpress-publikaciya-postov-s-pomoshhyu-xml-rpc-s-podderzhkoj-taksonomij.html)

Comment: Спасибо, кажется я уже скопипастил какой-то пример из инетаот сюда: http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/wordpress-xmlrpc-posting-content-from-outside-wordpress-admin-panel/